# Too many <title> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I have a site here: https://www.idee-creative.co.uk Where I have added custom fields to enable me to add custom page titles and descriptions for SEO purposes.

However, the problem is, Wordpress seems to also be displaying it's own title tag containing the sites title and tagline from the general setting...

The Wordpress title must come in from the  tag inside my header.php page (I think anyway).

So, is there a way to remove the wordpress page title and just show the page title I created in custom fields?

The code I use to display the custom field is just:

```
<title><?php the_field('seo_page_title'); ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php the_field('seo_page_description'); ?>"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `wp_title()` for setting the title of your page as

```
wp_title( string $sep = '&raquo;', bool $display = true, string $seplocation = '' )
```

You can get a full reference here [Adding Custom Title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)

Comment: Thanks - So should I rewrite my code and include the custom fields I have inside the wp_title() tag? or wont they work inside wp_title() ? - It seems it would be easier to get rid of the wordpress title tags and leave what I have? is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the `header.php` file or modify the title tag within JavaScript (I think). You cannot override the `<title>` tag within an HTML page by just placing your own after.

Hope that helped =)